# Foreach Loop within a Form

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, forms

I'm using wordpress to create a website and I need to create a form that allows users to select a number from a dropdown list and then populate the form with that amount of data

Since I'm new with wordpress I'm using the Caldera Forms plugin to build the forms but there's no repeater or something similar to use

I'm not any good with php to create a script for this and can't find any other solution online

IF I Select 3 from the dropdown the following needs to display on the form

````
Sample 1 Date:[Current Date]
Code:[text]
Flock:[text]
Species:[text]
Age (days):[text]
House:[text]
Analysis Required:[text]

SAMPLE 2

Sample 2 Date:[Current Date]
Code:[text]
Flock:[text]
Species:[text]
Age (days):[text]
House:[text]
Analysis Required)[text]

SAMPLE 3

Sample 3 Date:[Current Date]
Code:[text]
Flock:[text]
Species:[text]
Age (days):[text]
House:[text]
Analysis Required:[text]```

edit: Caldera forms has a Conditional tab that allows you to add if statements
````

Comment: You need javascript to replicate forms on the page.. you can also do it with PHP via ajax but it's not practical. Wordpress ships with jQuery so it will be easier to do this.

Comment: I don't think a plugin has an option for that, yet...

Comment: @OliverMGrech Im new with php and javascript and not even sure how to implement it into wordpress

Comment: I don't know any easy solution for this. I think this can be solved with lot of lines of JS. All forms are the same, changes only number "Sample [number]". So instead using dropdown, you should have one sample form and button below "Add another sample", on click just create another div with same fields. On submit don't do default form, bus just loop trough sample divs and put everything to single array var samples = {'sample-1': {'code': 'code', 'Flock': 'text', ..}, ..} post this to admin ajax and parse how you want in backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you decide to do without plugin, this is part for front end, to add remove  and submit samples https://jsfiddle.net/Beneris/ns7dq9Lz/39/

You still need to add ajax_url to footer.php

```
<script>var ajax_url = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";</script>
```

And function to process submitted data, to functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_samples', 'ajax_save_samples' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_samples', 'ajax_save_samples' );

function ajax_save_samples() {
    $json= strip_tags($_POST['json']);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    foreach ($data as $d) {}
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure the javascript + JQ code 
In what js folder do i add it or do i have to create a new folder?

Comment: Usually all styles, js and php functions shuld be added to your site activated theme files. So look what js files are included to load and add to those files. Or create new file in activated theme assets folder and add hook to load that file.